# Any configuring Visual Studios 2010 for LAMP stack as primary use?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have had great success with Visual Studios for past C# development, but now my primary focus is in the LAMP stack with PHP as the server-side script. I have tools for this, but there are a few features I have seen in a recent tutorial in Visual Studios that I would like to try out (in particular jQuery extension). I am looking for if anything, ways others have used as a primary development tool and/or have used as a secondary. I am looking at minimizing unused menu items for only those in my LAMP stack, i.e. PHP, MySQL, html, css, JavaScript and frameworks for these.

AND, I am not looking for a debate that will get this locked-out, but I would be interested if others have taken this path and decided VS is not for LAMP or at least server-side parts of LAMP.

Comment: FYI I think you want WAMP, not LAMP as visual studio does not run on Linux.

Comment: @DanielA.White - AFAIK, [wine](http://www.winehq.org) has supported Visual Studio for quite a while now, though probably not 2010 and 2012.

Comment: If you want to use a LAMP stack I suggest you learn how to use vim

Comment: @AdrianCornish I have vim and more so vi on the to-do list but that is a language in itself. Honestly, I am doing some tutorials/videos at pluralsight.com and they use VS, so I just wanted to play along.
Btw Daniel, I want to run the Visual Studios on Windows, but work with sites that run on the LAMP stack. So this has nothing to do with what OS I am using.

Comment: @Shane - the learning curve for vi/vim is very steep in the beginning (many years ago my first programming job when I had to use it - after a week I decided to write my own editor over the weekend - mon morning I decided to learn vi :-) - it is not an IDE (although it can kinda be used as one) - There are some free PHP IDE's out there but once you learn vim you will never look back - I always install it on windows boxes now. Always preferred the command line approach - so I know what I doing - rather than some check box somewhere under some menu item

Comment: @AdrianCornish - Maybe starting with vim is a good idea. I have spent many weekends going for vi and end up finding Ubuntu to dual-boot, add to VMWare, set up on old laptop, then try to decide if RedHat is better to start learning on, learning Linux, then trying to migrate Windows software I hate to let go of.. ha ha! it never ends. I am using PHPStorm and it does everything I need for LAMP, so maybe I should not mix the technology and stick with what is working.. keep the VS for Microsoft stuff.

Comment: @Shane Agree - local tools are better suited :-) my fav useless vim command is `g?G` but dont do it on a file you want or dont save it :-)